# Extending scala case class without constantly duplicating constructors vals?

Tags: scala, inheritance

Is there a way to extend a case class without constantly picking up new vals along the way?

For example this doesn't work:

```
case class Edge(a: Strl, b: Strl)
case class EdgeQA(a: Strl, b: Strl, right: Int, asked: Int) extends Edge(a, b)
```

`"a" conflicts with "a"`, so I'm forced to rename to `a1`. But I don't want all kinds of extra public copies of "a" so I made it private.

```
case class Edge(a: Strl, b: Strl)
case class EdgeQA(private val a1: Strl, private val b1: Strl, right: Int, asked: Int) extends Edge(a, b)
```

This just doesn't seem clean to me... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

As the previous commenter mentioned: case class extension should be avoided but you could convert your Edge class into a trait.

If you want to avoid the private statements you can also mark the variables as override

```
trait Edge{
  def a:Strl
  def b:Strl
}

case class EdgeQA(override val a:Strl, override val b:Strl, right:Int, asked:Int ) extends Edge
```

Don't forget to prefer `def` over `val` in traits

Comment: We lose the advantage of the Edge as a standalone class: before it could be instantiated and it had the object Factory methods

Comment: but I still need to redeclare a and b. What if the trait had some default value for a and be and I wish to use those values themselves.

Comment: Can you explain why def is preferred in traits?

Comment: Please do explain your last statement.  Is it because the implementation can be either a function or a variable?

Comment: `"case class extension should be avoided`". Can you please explain why, @bajohns?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642053/when-to-use-val-or-def-in-scala-traits) is an explanation on why to use def vs val

Comment: Good but not perfect, we can't perfom sanity check on the variables this way without duplicating the code. Fortunately, Scala 3 will allow trait values as shown in [this example](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-example-project/blob/master/src/main/scala/TraitParams.scala).

Answer (score 59):

This solution offers some advantages over the previous solutions:

```
trait BaseEdge {
  def a: Strl
  def b: Strl
}
case class Edge(a:Strl, b:Strl) extends BaseEdge
case class EdgeQA(a:Strl, b:Strl, right:Int, asked:Int ) extends BaseEdge
```

In this way:

- you don't have redundant `val`s, and
- you have 2 case classes.

Comment: this is definitely better

Answer (score 15):

Case classes can't be extended via subclassing. Or rather, the sub-class of a case class cannot be a case class itself.

Comment: So why are there `final case class`es?  The `final` _LocalModifier_ is what prevents the extension of a `case class`, not some other language prohibition.  See §5.2, p.63 of the [Scala Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf)

Comment: Final prevents extending a case class with anything ( i.e. case and not case classes), in addition to the built-in restriction to extend case classes with case classes.

Answer (score 5):

Starting in `Scala 3`, [traits can have parameters](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/trait-parameters.html):

```
trait Edge(a: Strl, b: Strl)
case class EdgeQA(a: Strl, b: Strl, c: Int, d: Int) extends Edge(a, b)
```