# When to use val or def in Scala traits?

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

I was going through the [effective scala slides](http://www.slideshare.net/mircodotta/effective-scala) and it mentions on slide 10 to never use `val` in a `trait` for abstract members and use `def` instead. The slide does not mention in detail why using abstract `val` in a `trait` is an anti-pattern. I would appreciate it if someone can explain best practice around using val vs def in a trait for abstract methods

Answer (score 138, accepted):

A `def` can be implemented by either of a `def`, a `val`, a `lazy val` or an `object`. So it's the most abstract form of defining a member. Since traits are usually abstract interfaces, saying you want a `val` is saying *how* the implementation should do. If you ask for a `val`, an implementing class cannot use a `def`.

A `val` is needed only if you need a stable identifier, e.g. for a path-dependent type. That's something you usually don't need.

---

Compare:

```
trait Foo { def bar: Int }

object F1 extends Foo { def bar = util.Random.nextInt(33) } // ok

class F2(val bar: Int) extends Foo // ok

object F3 extends Foo {
  lazy val bar = { // ok
    Thread.sleep(5000)  // really heavy number crunching
    42
  }
}
```

If you had

```
trait Foo { val bar: Int }
```

you wouldn't be able to define `F1` or `F3`.

---

Ok, and to confuse you and answer @om-nom-nom—using abstract `val`s can cause initialisation problems:

```
trait Foo { 
  val bar: Int 
  val schoko = bar + bar
}

object Fail extends Foo {
  val bar = 33
}

Fail.schoko  // zero!!
```

This is an ugly problem which in my personal opinion should go away in future Scala versions by fixing it in the compiler, but yes, currently this is also a reason why one should not use abstract `val`s.

**Edit** (Jan 2016): You are allowed to override an abstract `val` declaration with a `lazy val` implementation, so that would also prevent the initialisation failure.

Comment: words about tricky initialization order and surprising nulls?

Comment: Yeah... I would't even go there. True these are also arguments against val, but I think the basic motivation should just be to hide implementation.

Comment: This may have changed in a recent Scala version (2.11.4 as of this comment), but you can override a `val` with a `lazy val`. Your assertion that you wouldn't be able to create `F3` if `bar` was a `val` is not correct. That said, abstract members in traits should always be `def`'s

Comment: The Foo/Fail example works as expected if you replace `val schoko = bar + bar` with `lazy val schoko = bar + bar`. That's one way of having some control over the initialization order. Also, using `lazy val` instead of `def` in the derived class avoids recomputation.

Comment: @om-nom-nom , Could you please elaborate more on initialisation problem or null issue with using val in trait? Any links are much appreciated!

Comment: @BlueSky well, it's explained a bit in above answer body (check out edit starting with _using abstract vals can cause initialisation problems_), are you eager for more?

Comment: If you change `val bar: Int` to `def bar: Int` `Fail.schoko` is still zero.

Comment: Yes, or you could even have non-abstract `def` or `val` which is overridden by a `val` or a `def` which accesses a `val` and run into the same problem. The problem here is using a non-final member during initialization at all, and whether you declare it as `def` or a `val` is a red herring.

Comment: happened to me and glad that i find this edit in this post, abstract int vals were being zero exactly it is described here

Comment: To me this says you shouldn't define a `val` in a trait that references other members. Changing `val bar: Int` in `trait Foo` doesn't solve the initialization problem. In the `trait Foo` example, it's fine to have `val bar: Int` but it isn't fine to have `val schoko = bar + bar` regardless of how `bar` is defined.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer not use `val` in traits because the val declaration has unclear and non-intuitive order of initialization. You may add a trait to already working hierarchy and it would break all things that worked before, see my topic: [why using plain val in non-final classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091689/why-using-plain-val-in-non-final-classes)

You should keep all things about using this val declarations in mind which eventually road you to an error.

---

#### Update with more complicated example

But there are times when you could not avoid using `val`. As @0__ had mentioned sometimes you need a stable identifier and `def` is not one.

I would provide an example to show what he was talking about:

```
trait Holder {
  type Inner
  val init : Inner
}
class Access(val holder : Holder) {
  val access : holder.Inner =
    holder.init
}
trait Access2 {
  def holder : Holder
  def access : holder.Inner =
    holder.init
}
```

This code produces the error:

```
 StableIdentifier.scala:14: error: stable identifier required, but Access2.this.holder found.
    def access : holder.Inner =
```

If you take a minute to think you would understand that compiler has a reason to complain. In the `Access2.access` case it could not derive return type by any means. `def holder` means that it could be implemented in broad way. It could return different holders for each call and that holders would incorporate different `Inner` types. But Java virtual machine expects the same type to be returned.

Comment: Order of initialization shouldn't matter, but instead we get surprising NPE's during runtime, vis-a-vis anti-pattern.

Comment: scala has declarative syntax that hide imperative nature behind. Sometimes that imperativeness works counter-intuitive

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers about avoiding abstract `val`s for the reason that it provides more options to implementations.

There are cases where you might need them:

- For a path-dependent type (as mentioned by @0__).
- Where implementations might be expensive and it is used in a concrete `def`.
- (Are there others? If so please comment and I'll add them in).

The more important things to know is when it is safe to override something with a `val` and to have a `lazy val` that does not override something.

---

**Rule 1**: Never override a `val` or `def` with a non-lazy `val` unless it is a constructor parameter:

```scala
trait TraitWithVal {
  // It makes no difference if this is concrete or abstract.
  val a: String
  val b: String = a
}

class OverrideValWithVal extends TraitWithVal {
  // Bad: b will be null.
  override val a: String = "a"
}

class OverrideValWithLazyVal extends TraitWithVal {
  // Ok: b will be "a".
  override lazy val a: String = "a"
}

// Ok: b will be "a".
class OverrideValWithConstructorVal(override val a: String = "a") extends TraitWithVal

//class OverrideValWithDef extends TraitWithVal {
//  // Compilation error: method a needs to be a stable, immutable value.
//  override def a: String = "a"
//}

println((new OverrideValWithVal).b) // null
println((new OverrideValWithLazyVal).b) // a
println((new OverrideValWithConstructorVal).b) // a
```

The same rule applies to a `def`:

```scala
trait TraitWithDef {
  // It makes no difference if this is concrete or abstract.
  def a: String
  val b: String = a
}

class OverrideDefWithVal extends TraitWithDef {
  // Bad: b will be null.
  override val a: String = "a"
}

class OverrideDefWithLazyVal extends TraitWithDef {
  // Ok: b will be "a".
  override lazy val a: String = "a"
}

// Ok: b will be "a".
class OverrideDefWithConstructorVal(override val a: String = "a") extends TraitWithDef

class OverrideDefWithDef extends TraitWithDef {
  // Ok: b will be "a".
  override def a: String = "a"
}

println((new OverrideDefWithVal).b) // null
println((new OverrideDefWithLazyVal).b) // a
println((new OverrideDefWithConstructorVal).b) // a
println((new OverrideDefWithDef).b) // a
```

You might be wondering whether it would be ok to override a `val` with another `val` so long as it isn't used during initialisation. There is at least one edge cases which break this:

```scala
trait TraitWithValAndLazyVal {
  val a: String = "A"
  def b: String = a
}

class OverrideLazyValWithVal extends TraitWithValAndLazyVal {
  // Bad: This on its own is ok but not if it is indirectly referenced during initialisation and overridden.
  override val a = "a"
  val c = b
}

class OverrideValWithVal extends OverrideLazyValWithVal {
  override val a = "a"
}

println((new OverrideValWithVal).a) // a
println((new OverrideValWithVal).b) // a
println((new OverrideValWithVal).c) // null
```

Given that we already apply this rule to overriding `def`s then this makes using `val`s a little more acceptable in my opinion.

If you use a linter to enforce the `override` keyword and make sure your code never has any `override val` definitions then you are good.

You might be able to allow `final override val` but it's possible there are other edge cases that I haven't thought of.

---

**Rule 2**: Never use a `lazy val` that is not overriding another `lazy val` or `def`.

As far as I can tell there also is no good reason to have a `lazy val` that *isn't* overriding something. All the examples that I can come up with where it is needed, it is needed only because it violates **Rule 1** and exposes the edge case I described earlier.

For example:

```scala
trait NormalLookingTrait {
  def a: String
  val b: String = a
}

trait TraitWithAbstractVal extends NormalLookingTrait {
  val c: String
}

class OverrideValWithVal extends TraitWithAbstractVal {
  override def a: String = c
  override val c = "a"
}

println((new OverrideValWithVal).a) // a
println((new OverrideValWithVal).b) // null
println((new OverrideValWithVal).c) // a
```

So we make `b` a `lazy val`:

```scala
trait SuspiciousLookingTrait2 {
  def a: String
  lazy val b: String = a
}

trait TraitWithAbstractVal2 extends SuspiciousLookingTrait2 {
  val c: String
}

class OverrideValWithVal2 extends TraitWithAbstractVal2 {
  override def a: String = c
  override val c = "a"
}

println((new OverrideValWithVal2).a) // a
println((new OverrideValWithVal2).b) // a
println((new OverrideValWithVal2).c) // a
```

Looks ok, except when we go one step further:

```scala
trait SuspiciousLookingTrait2 {
  def a: String
  lazy val b: String = a
}

trait TraitWithAbstractVal2 extends SuspiciousLookingTrait2 {
  val c: String
}

class OverrideValWithVal2 extends TraitWithAbstractVal2 {
  override def a: String = c
  override val c = "a"
  val d = b
}

class OverrideValWithVal3 extends OverrideValWithVal2 {
  override val c = "a"
}

println((new OverrideValWithVal3).a) // a
println((new OverrideValWithVal3).b) // null
println((new OverrideValWithVal3).c) // a
println((new OverrideValWithVal3).d) // null
```

I now get what people mean when they say to only use `lazy` when it is absolutely necessary and never for delayed initialisation.

It's probably safe to break this rule if the trait / class is `final` but even that smells fishy.

Comment: I just realised that rule 1 also applies to classes with concrete `val`s which means that if a classes uses another `val` anywhere in it's initialisation then the referenced `val` has to be final or risk `null`s when extended.

Answer (score -4):

Always using def seems a bit awkward since something like this won't work:

```
trait Entity { def id:Int}

object Table { 
  def create(e:Entity) = {e.id = 1 }  
}
```

You will get the following error:

```
error: value id_= is not a member of Entity
```

Comment: No relevant. You have an error too if you use val instead of def (error: reassignment to val), and that's perfectly logical.

Comment: Not if you use `var`.  The point is, if the they are fields they should be designated as such.  I just think having everything as `def` is short sighted.

Comment: @Dimitry, sure, using `var` let's you break encapsulation. But using a `def` (or a `val`) is preferred over a global variable. I think what you're looking for is something like `case class ConcreteEntity(override val id: Int) extends Entity` so that you can create it from `def create(e: Entity) = ConcreteEntity(1)` This is safer than breaking the encapsulation and allowing any class to change Entity.