# Same class data member name in Trait and Case Class in Scala

Tags: scala

If I have a trait :

```
 trait Person
 {
    val name: String
 }
```

and then a case class:

```
 case class Student(val name: String) extends Person
 {
     ......   
 }
```

Are these two "name" the same thing?  If I pass a value to Student's "name" field, can I access to this value through Person's name? I guess not.  Or Student's "name" overrides Person's name?   I guess I can only access Student's name via the Student class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the abstract field in the Person trait with a field in your Student class, so your guess is correct.

You might want to consider some small changes. 
You could make the abstract definition in the trait a "def". That gives you more flexibility in overriding, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19642301/52055

Also, in case classes, the "val" keyword is assumed for your class parameters, so you don't need to provide it. So you'd end up with

```
 trait Person
 {
    def name: String
 }

 case class Student(name: String) extends Person
 {
     ......   
 }
```

Comment: Thank you.  So in order to access name from Person, i have to do something like Person.name = Student.name ?

Comment: No. Or rather, not sure I understand what you mean. If you have a method that expects a Person, say "p", it's fine to say p.name. The actual implementation you get can be a student, or anything else that implements the Person trait.