# scala type parameter as object type

Tags: scala, inheritance, typeclass, value-class

How can I achieve this:

```
final case class ChairId(id: String)

trait GeneratorLike[TO, TC <: AbstractId] {
  val prefix: String
  def generate(): TC = TO.apply(prefix + "-" + UUID.randomUUID())
}

implicit object ChairIdGenerator extends GeneratorLike[ChairId.type, ChairId] {
  val prefix: String = "CHAIR"
}

implicit def IdFn[TO, TC <: AbstractId](x: TO)(implicit ev: GeneratorLike[TO, TC]): GeneratorLike[TO, TC] = ev

//right now I can call:
ChairId.generate()
```

I don't want to define companion object for that situation and I wondered if there is a chance to extend object with use of implicits?

When I do (I use TO as TypeObject and TC as TypeClass naming) `idFn[TO, TC]` I want TO to be object that implements `def apply(id: String): TC` can I enforce that? And how would I get to use this function? It feels totally impossible to call function on type parameter :/

Comment: You can't call a *method* on a type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* impossible to call a method on a type parameter, because it represents a *type* and not an *object*. You can call a method on an object, because it is something that exists, but a type is an abstract concept. I don't know what your motivation is for wanting to implicitly add `generate()` to companion objects, because it actually requires just as much code to define an implicit `GeneratorLike` than it does to define the companion for `ChairId`.

If you force `GeneratorLike` to have an `apply` method (which can be implemented by case class `apply`), and remove the first type parameter, this will work.

```
trait GeneratorLike[TC <: AbstractId] { this: Singleton =>
  val prefix: String
  def apply(id: String): TC
  def generate(): TC = apply(prefix + "-" + UUID.randomUUID())
}

abstract class AbstractId

final case class ChairId(id: String) extends AbstractId

object ChairId extends GeneratorLike[ChairId] {
  val prefix = "CHAIR"
}

scala> ChairId.generate()
res0: ChairId = ChairId(CHAIR-60bb01c7-af95-46c7-af45-0b3fa78b3080)
```

Comment: I have case classes and objects automatically generated that's why I didn't want to change that. Your solution is nice and clean no doubt.

Comment: `implicit def IdFn[TC <: AbstractId](to: {def apply(s: String): TC})(implicit ev: GeneratorLike[TC]): SpecGeneratorLike[TC] = new SpecGeneratorLike[TC](ev, to)
class GeneratorLike[TC <: AbstractId](ev: PrefixLike[TC], x: {def apply(s: String): TC}) {
    def generate(): TC = x.apply(ev.prefix + "-" + UUID.randomUUID())
  }`

What do you think about something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Structural typing is not a particularly good idea on the JVM, so always try to avoid the `def test(x: {def apply(s: String)}): TC` type stuff because it is implemented using reflection which can be a dog performance wise.

Second, you should probably avoid using `val` inside a `trait`. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642053/when-to-use-val-or-def-in-scala-traits).

The approach you have considered is actually the right one, and namely type classes.

```
trait HasGenerator[T] {
  def apply(uuid: String): T 
  def generate[T : Generator] = apply(Generator[T].generate)
}

final case class ChairId(id: String) 

object ChairId extends HasGenerator[ChairId]

trait Generator[TO] {
  def prefix: String
  def generate(): String = prefix + "-" + UUID.randomUUID()
  def apply(): String = generate
}

object Generator {
  def apply[T : Generator] = implicitly[Generator[T]]
}

// Notice .type is not necessary
implicit object ChairIdGenerator extends Generator[ChairId] {
  override def prefix = "CHAIR"
}
```

Why not just use:

```
ChairId(Generator[ChairId])
```

This all seems like overkill though so you can quite easily somehow. It's worth fleshing out your requirements a bit more because type classes don't really seem super necessary just yet. You could just do with:

**Update**

If you use something like the `HasGenerator` that I have added above in conjunction with the companion object, you can now successfully call `ChairId.generate()`

Comment: This one I don't like because you can easily mess up with something like:
`ChairId(implicitly[Generator[TableId]]())`

I have classes / objects used in production code and simply want to add nice interface for writing tests. One of things I though would be to add possibility to generate ID's and tightly couple prefix with proper case class.
Because we read most of our time code I really wanted to provide solution where we can just write `ChairId.generate()` or `TableId.generate()`

Comment: Hi @kpbochenek I would suggest a very different approach then. Have a look here: https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/develop/phantom-dsl/src/test/scala/com/websudos/phantom/tables/package.scala#L41

Comment: @kpbochenek I've improved my solution to give you what you wanted.