# Cake pattern with val members which depend on abstract members

Tags: scala, default, traits

So take this trait

```
trait SomeTrait{
  val x:Int
  val y:Int
  val z=x*y
}
```

And then this implementation

```
class SomeImpl extends SomeTrait{
  val x=5
  val y=2
  println(z) //prints 0 why?
}
```

Why does it print 0? and how can I avoid that! I want z to be a val, in case it is some kind of expensive computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z` must be marked as either `lazy val` or `def`

```
trait SomeTrait{
  val x:Int
  val y:Int
  lazy val z=x*y
}
```

For a detailed explanation, refer to [When to use val or def in Scala traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642053/when-to-use-val-or-def-in-scala-traits)