# class needs to be abstract since value element in trait is not defined

Tags: scala

I was playing around with dependent types and run into this error:

```
some.scala:17: error: class B needs to be abstract, since value element in trait
 Buffer of type B.this.T is not defined
```

using this code:

```
package types

object Demo {

trait Buffer {
  type T
  val element: T
}

abstract class Wee extends Buffer {
    type T <:    Integer
    val s = element - 2

}

class B extends Wee {
}

}
```

Could someone decrypt what value element stands for?

Comment: Scala 101, never use val in trait: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642053/when-to-use-val-or-def-in-scala-traits

Comment: @flavian, corrcted to def, same error

Comment: What do you want to use as the `element` in the `B` class? You need to add it there in order to make it working.

Comment: You have declared a value `element` but provided no definition for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you're using an abstract type member for no conceivable reason. It's not directly related to your error, but alas.

```
package types

object Demo {

trait Buffer[T] {
  def element: T
}

abstract class Wee extends Buffer[Integer] {
  def s: Integer = element - 2

}
```

Ok now for the actual failure, it's pretty obvious and straightforward, you have not provided an implementation for `element`. Your `Wee` class `extends Buffer`, so any concrete implementor must provide an implementation for `element` by your very contract.

A `trait` or `abstract class` can have abstract members, a normal `class` cannot. Ergo, kaboom, compiler is telling you to get your OOP up to scratch.

```
class B extends Wee {
  val element = 5
}
```

Or better yet:

```
class B(val element: Integer) extends Wee
```